# Boostrap glyphicons not working with out of the box laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I cannot see glyphicons with laravel 5. I tried putting /fonts direcory into /public laravel folder:

/laravel/public/css/app.css (compiled boostrap .less files from laravel/resources/assets/less/bootstrap) 
/laravel/public/fonts/ fonts from boostrap website.

Still nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Fixed it. Apparently laravel elixir was turned on and I had css builds, so had to put fonts into /public/build.